# Unable to put Access Token to SOAP Client using php for Salesforce API

Tags: php, api, oauth, salesforce

I am using SOAP client of Sales Force for php to make api calls like below

```
$client = new SforcePartnerClient();
$client->createConnection($sfPath);
$client->login($username, $password);
$client->query($query);
```

Above works fine.
To allow users to login through the Oauth.
Now I had retrieve the Access Token usin REST api from Oauth.
But not able to find any function that uses this to login in SOAP api.So I like to know how we can put this access token in SOAP login api.
I had tried

```
$client->setSessionHeader($accessToken);
```

But this doesn't work.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out how to use access token for SOAP api.
I did the following and it worked

```
 $client = new SforcePartnerClient();
 $client->createConnection($sfPath);
 $client->setSessionHeader($accessToken);
 $client->setEndpoint('https://'.$instanceUrl.'/services/Soap/u/44.0/'.$orgID);
 $client->query($query);
```